# Required XML attribute 'adsize' was missing (google play service)

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

There are so question like that but it's not duplicate

because i have already used         xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
and i have done code mostly in java

I want to use google play service for ads

I have used below java code

```
    com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView adView = (com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView) activity.findViewById(R.id.adview);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(activity.getString(R.string.admob_id));
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

and following xml code

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
```

but i am getting error in banner is like

Requred  XML attribute 'adsize' was missing

Comment: try to add Adview in LinearLayout, first take linearlayout

Comment: you have missing ads:adSize="BANNER" attribute in xml

Answer (score 5):

Change the namespace to

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

**Ad.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**NOTE :**

Use this Namespace for new SDK

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: Great Answer, It is really difficult to find this. +1

Comment: Thank you, xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" resolved my problem. it's so stupid that AS does not add the correct name space ...

Answer (score 3):

Try add "ads:adSize" to XML like below:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adview"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove "adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);" from your java file.

Refer below:

Here is the XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/hello"/>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       ads:adSize="BANNER"
                       ads:adUnitId="INSERT_YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is your java file

```
package com.google.example.gms.ads.xml;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * A simple {@link Activity} which embeds an AdView in its layout XML.
 */
public class BannerXMLSample extends Activity {

  private static final String TEST_DEVICE_ID = "INSERT_YOUR_TEST_DEVICE_ID_HERE";

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // The "loadAdOnCreate" and "testDevices" XML attributes no longer available.
    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice(TEST_DEVICE_ID)
        .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
  }
}
```

Refer the example here
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/banner-xml