# Showing error Required XML attribute "adSize" was missing

Tags: android, xml, admob, ads

I am implementing banner ads, but getting the error "Required XML attribute "adsize" was missing". I was using [the developer.google.com link to add admob](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#create_a_new_project)

I also visited other stackoverflow questions like as [Required XML attribute 'adsize' was missing (google play service)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629638/required-xml-attribute-adsize-was-missing-google-play-service)

and I have already implemented everything but the error remains the same. Here is the code.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.abhishek.canddatastructureprograms.MainActivity">



<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/sample_content_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">

 </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

added the following code in onCreate() method.

```
AdView mAdview= (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);


    //AdRequest mAdRequest= new AdRequest().Builder.build();

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
            .addTestDevice("9F099BD5E5700664591DEC5FDC92A40E")  // An example device ID
            .build();

    mAdview.loadAd(request);
```

**Please let me know if I need to add any more details or code.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code seems to be right. Try to remove all left and right paddings or margins, maybe you get this error because you have too small screen to show add.

Comment: Woah! Thanks a lot!! It works now. I never even thought that this could effect it.